# What's wrong with this custom block's loot table? It's supposed to choose drop by testing for silk touch, but non-enchanted pick drops both options

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons, minecraft-behavior-packs

I have a custom block that is supposed to be only obtainable using a Silk Touch pickaxe. If mined with a pickaxe without Silk Touch, it should drop end stone instead, and if mined with the wrong tool, it should drop nothing.

Instead, it drops the correct loot only when a Silk Touch pickaxe is used. When a regular pickaxe is used, it drops *both* itself and an end stone block; when mined with the wrong tool, the same thing happens.

From [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/loottableconditions?view=minecraft-bedrock-stable), "Applying a condition to a pool allows you execute the entire pool based on the conditions defined." In my custom block's loot table, each pool has its own (mutually exclusive) condition, so I'm not sure what's causing multiple drops (which would imply matching both or possibly all 3 conditions, which should be impossible).

Here is the loot table .json file:

```
{
    "pools": [
        // Give rhizome block if mined using a Silk Touch pickaxe
        {
            "condition": "query.equipped_item_any_tag('slot.weapon.mainhand', 'minecraft:is_pickaxe') && query.has_silk_touch",
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "name": "end:rhizome"
                }
            ]
        },
        // Give end stone if mined with a pickaxe without Silk Touch
        {
            "condition": "query.equipped_item_any_tag('slot.weapon.mainhand', 'minecraft:is_pickaxe') && !query.has_silk_touch",
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "name": "minecraft:end_stone"
                }
            ]
        },
        // Drop nothing if mined with anything other than a pickaxe
        {
            "condition": "!query.equipped_item_any_tag('slot.weapon.mainhand', 'minecraft:is_pickaxe')",
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "empty"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Rearranging the three pools does not change the result. So, it doesn't matter whether the "has silk touch" condition comes first or third: it's still the only one that works as intended.

I also tested swapping out the condition strings with condition arrays of the following form:

```
"conditions": [
    {
        "condition": "same molang queries here"
    }
]
```

but the same problem was still happening.

Comment: @pppery If there's a rule that all questions tagged with [tag:minecraft-addons] must also have the [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition] tag, it seems like that bit of information ought to be in the tag wiki (it currently isn't).

Comment: So feel free to suggest it. You have just as much rights as I do there. It's been standard practice here since forever that every question is tagged with the game it applies to, which is *Minecraft: Bedrock Edition* in this case.

Comment: @pppery Oh, I didn't realize that. I only looked at the description of the addons tag and saw that it already mentioned Minecraft Bedrock Edition (but not that tag), so thought it might be redundant to have both. Thanks for the info and the retag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different way of accomplishing the same thing, without using conditions in the loot table:

**Loot table for the block:** (set to a single, empty entry)

```
{
    "pools": [
        // A placeholder; the actual drop will be determined in main.js
        {
            "rolls": 1,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "empty"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Script file (main.js; uses @minecraft/server version 1.10.0-beta):** -- This is where we'll test for use of silk touch pickaxe vs. unenchanted pickaxe vs. no pickaxe

```
import { world, system, ItemStack, ItemComponentTypes } from "@minecraft/server"

// For use inside the .playerBreakBlock event listener, for getting the broken block's former coordinates
// Properties will be player names (type String); values will be Block objects
var lastBlockHitByPlayer = {};

world.afterEvents.entityHitBlock.subscribe(event => {
    // Keep a record of the last block the player hit
    if (event.damagingEntity.typeId === "minecraft:player") {
        lastBlockHitByPlayer[event.damagingEntity.name] = event.hitBlock;
    }
});

world.afterEvents.playerBreakBlock.subscribe(event => {
    if (event.brokenBlockPermutation.type.id === "end:rhizome") {
        const stack = event.itemStackAfterBreak;
        const player = event.player;
        // Block will drop rhizome if mined with a silk touch pickaxe (this happens automatically)
        if (stack !== undefined && stack.typeId.includes("_pickaxe") && !stack.getComponent(ItemComponentTypes.Enchantable).hasEnchantment("silk_touch")) {
            // Drop regular end stone if the block is mined with a non-silk-touch pickaxe
            (async () => {
                // For .playerBreakBlock, there's no direct way to access the block's coordinates (because it isn't there anymore?). Instead, the coordinates
                // of the block that has just been broken should be the same as those of the most recent block which the player hit (since hitting the block - left click - is a prerequisite to breaking it).
                await player.dimension.spawnItem(new ItemStack("minecraft:end_stone"), {x: lastBlockHitByPlayer[player.name].x, y: lastBlockHitByPlayer[player.name].y, z: lastBlockHitByPlayer[player.name].z});
            })();
        } // Otherwise, drop nothing
    }
});
```

With this method, the custom block drops the correct loot for each case.